# Texture shown wrong in rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing

I have created a 3d bird with body and feathers.
I have here an extracted feather with feather material.
I can see it properly when I see it in the rendered window with Cycles, but if I click the render button the feather has the material that I apply to the bird.
Before that the feathers had many materials but I deleted all the wrong ones but the final rendering is always wrong.

[image: Left: correct feather. Right: wrong feather after rendering]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have material override in render layer:

[image]

It replaces all materials in the scene by this one. Remove material from here by clicking cross-icon